# Website Load Time takes forever

Tags: performance

Hi weve got two dashboard in wordpress, One is the admin dashboard of the website and the admin dashboard of the client. For example my website name is www.abc.com, inside the admin dashboard theres a tab called VA ABC. So whenerver I click the VA ABC it will go to another dashboard where I can add new members, add client, upload screenshots etc. The problem is whenever I click the VA ABC it takes for almost 30s to load up and it really sucks.

Comment: I'm not sure how this question can be answered, all we know is that there's a page on your WP Admin dashboard that takes 30s to load, which could be anything. If this is a 3rd party plugin you should contact their support

Comment: **A quick tip for getting great answers**: Consider starting by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem and any difficulties in solving it yourself. The first paragraph is the second thing most readers will see, so make it a good one. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to.